# Field variableValues not working on graphql library execution on node

Tags: graphql

I'm playing with the graphql library (https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) on node but I'm having some hard time on passing variable attributes...

```
const variableValues = {
  routing, // String
  statuses, // Array
  date // Input type described in the query
}

return graphql({
  schema: schema,
  source: query,
  rootValue: resolvers,
  variableValues: variableValues
})
```

Unfortunately the variableValues are not passed to the resolver (if I log the context from the resolver, it show me that the variableValues is an empty object).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Variable values are not passed to your context. Variables are used to substitute values inside an operation. So instead of using literal values like this:

```
query GetUser {
  getUser(id: 42) {
    name
  }
}
```

we can write

```
query GetUser($userId: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $userId) {
    name
  }
}
```

In this particular example, `userId` would be exposed to the resolver for `getUser` as the `id` argument. The arguments for a field are provided as a the second parameter to the resolver function, separate from the context (which is the third parameter passed to the resolver).

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUser: (root, args, ctx) => {
      console.log(args.id) // prints the value of $userId
      ...
    },
  },
}
```

Note that variables may be used as arguments to directives as well, in which case they will not be passed to the resolver as part of the argument map at all.